# Encoding raw h.264 data to browser via Dash

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mpeg-dash

I have a live stream of raw h264 (no container) coming from a remote webcam. I wanna stream it live in browser using DASH. DASH requires creating mpd file (and segmentation). I found tools (such as mp4box) that accomplish that in static files, but i'm struggling to find a solution for live streams. any suggestions - **preferably using node.js modules**?

Threads i have checked:

1. **mp4box** - from one hand i saw this [comment](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/421) that states " *You cannot feed MP4Box with some live content. You need to feed MP4Box -live with pre-segmented chunks.*" on the other hand there's a lot of people directing to this [bitmovin tutorial](https://bitmovin.com/mp4box-dash-content-generation-x264/) which does implement a solution using mp4box. In the toturial they are using mp4box (which has a [node.js api implementation](https://github.com/gpac/mp4box.js/)) and [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) (which doesn't have node.js module? or is contained in ffmpeg/mp4box?)
2. **ngnix** - ngnix has a [module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) that support streaming to DASH using rtmp. for exemple in this [toturial](http://elelinux.blogspot.co.il/2015/11/dash-streaming-using-nginx.html#!/2015/11/dash-streaming-using-nginx.html). I prefer not to go this path - as mention i'm trying to do it all in node.js.

Although i read couple of posts with similar problem, I couldn't find a suitable solution. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would also appreciate explanation - From my basic understanding the h264 encoded video need a container (such as mp4) in order to be transmitted. does DASH encpsulate the raw h264 stream without a container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical architecture is to send your live stream to a streaming server which will then do the heavy lifting to make the stream available to other devices, using streaming protocols such as HLS and DASH.

So the client devices connect to the server rather than to your browser.

This allows the video to be encoded and packaged to reach as many devices as possible with the server doing any transcoding necessary and potentially also creating different bit rate versions of your stream to allow for different network conditions, if you want to provide this level of service.

The typical structure is encoded stream (e.g. h.264 video), packaged into a container (e.g. mp4 fragmented) and delivered via a streaming protocol such as HLS or DASH.

Comment: I have a node server that accept the streaming from the webcam. What do you refer to when you're saying "streaming server"? a rtsp server..? I can't encapsulate my encoded h264 in mp4 because it's a live stream (kindly see my previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113805/wrap-h-264-stream-in-mp-4-container-and-stream-it-with-nodejs). I would really appreciate elaboration, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: By streaming server I mean a dedicated streamer server like https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org or https://www.wowza.com. The encapsulation in mp4 and DASH can happen on the streaming server.